# Updating tab badge dynamically on Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I wish to update dynamically a badge value, when I click on a button.

**tabs.html**

```
...
        <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Product" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Cart" tabIcon="cart" tabBadge="{{cartCount}}" tabBadgeStyle="danger"></ion-tab>
...
```

**tabs.ts**

```
export class TabsPage {
...
    cartCount = 0;

    tab1Root = ProductPage;
    tab2Root = CartPage;
...
}
```

**product.html**

```
<button ion-button full (click)="updateCart('add', p.id)">Buy Now</button>
```

**product.ts**

```
export class ProductPage {
...
    updateCart(action, id) {
        let cartCount = 1;

        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Success!',
            subTitle: 'You have added 1 product to the cart.',
            buttons: ['OK']
        });

        alert.present();
    }
...
}
```

As I tought, `let cartCount = 1;` does nothing. I've searched for a solution, but most of them are for Ionic 1 or AngularJS, which didn't helped me at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Ionic events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) for that. Please take a look at **[this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/49JrogoS7a5FdtJz1JWi?p=preview)**. Like you can see there, in the first tab we publish an event when the badge needs to be updated:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({..})
export class FirstTabPage {

  private count: number = 0;

  constructor(public events: Events) {}

  public updateTabBadge(): void {
    this.events.publish('cart:updated', ++this.count);
  }

}
```

And then we subscribe to that event in the page that contains both tabs:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class FirstTabPage {

  private count: number = 0;

  constructor(public events: Events) {}

  public updateTabBadge(): void {
    this.events.publish('cart:updated', ++this.count);
  }

}
```

And in the view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Tabs</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-tabs #myTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="First Tab"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Second Tab" [tabBadge]="cartCount"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Please also notice that *property binding* should be used instead of *string interpolation* to bind the `tabBadge` property: `[tabBadge]="cartCount"`

---

**UPDATE**

Just like [@skinny_jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2364907/skinny-jones) mentioned in the comments, you could also use `Subjects`/`Observables` to achieve the same result. You can find more information in **[this blog post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/update-tabs-badge-total-from-a-different-component/74977)**

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! I finally learned how to use the Events :-)

Comment: According to Ionic team, it is recommended to use Subject/Observables to update the badges: [Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/update-tabs-badge-total-from-a-different-component/74977)

Comment: @skinny_jones yes, that would be another way to solve the issue, but imho creating a new service just in order to declare a Subject/Observable is not the best way to solve this, since Events are also a core feature of Ionic (and I'm pretty sure that behind the scenes it probably uses subjects/observables as well)

Comment: @sebaferreras I understand, I just wanted to point to another option for those who are starting. I think it depends on what you're building, events should be fine, but also if I already have a database service for example it's easy to just use subject/observables.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot for bringing that out @skinny_jones. I've added your comment to the answer :)